# Cannot pass model instance variable to mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model that sends out invitations via email by parsing a CSV file for names and emails. I have a before_create that creates a url and saves it as an instance variable. After the record is created, it is supposed to send the results to the mailer, along with the instance variable of the URL. It seems like the URL is not being sent to the mailer as the emails are sent successfully, but with the URL. Below are the relevant lines of code. I am confirm that the invite_token is being created, so that is not an issue.

Note: I am using SmarterCSV gem to parse the csv and using the delayed_jobs gem to create a background process.

Let me explain the process:

Controller (not shown) receives the CSV and sends it to Invitation.import. The file is parsed and before the record is created, an invite token is created, then a URL is built. The email is then sent.

Thanks!

Controller: invitations_controller.rb

class InvitationsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :get_event #, only: [:create]

```
def new
    @invitation = @event.invitations.new
end

def create
    @invitation = @event.invitations.build(params[:invitation])
    @invitation.event_id = params[:event_id]

    if @invitation.save
        flash[:success] = "Invitation confirmed!"
        render 'static_pages/home'
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def import_csv
    @invitation = @event.invitations.new
end

def import
    Invitation.import(params[:file], params[:event_id])
    flash[:success] = "Invitations sent!"
    redirect_to @event
end

  private

     def get_event
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
     end
end
```

Model: Invitation.rb

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
       before_save { |user| user.email = user.email.downcase }
       before_create :create_invite_token
       before_create :build_url

@@url = "" #added 9/8/13

def self.import(file, id)

    file_path = file.path.to_s
    file_csv = SmarterCSV.process(file_path)

    file_csv.each do |x|
        x[:event_id] = id
        Invitation.delay.create! x
        UserMailer.delay.invitation_email(x, @@url)
    end
end

def build_url
  @@url = 'http://localhost:3000/confirmation/' + self.invite_token
end

private

    def create_invite_token
      self.invite_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
 end
```

Mailer: user_mailer.rb

```
def invitation_email(invitation, signup_url)
   @invitation = invitation
   @signup_url = signup_url

   mail(:to => invitation[:email], :subject => "You're invited!")
end
```

Invitation email:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
       <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <h2>Hi <%= @invitation[:name].split.first %>,</h2>
        <p>
          Click here: <%= @signup_url %>
        </p>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Can you please post your controller?

Comment: @jvperrin I've added the controller. Hope it helps! Thanks.

Comment: Are the urls different for each Invitation? If they are, I would recommend creating a migration that adds a url column to the invitations table. Otherwise, I think changing the instance variable to a class variable (@@url) would work well. I think the issue that is occurring here is that the instance variable @url is not available in the self.import method because it is only defined for an instance of the Invitation class, not for the class itself.

Comment: @jvperrin I added the class variable (@@url) and unless I added it incorrectly, I am still unable to pass the invite token to the mailer.

Comment: Since the class variable is not working, I would try adding a migration that adds a url column for invitations, since I would imagine each invitation has a different url. Then you should be able to just call self.url. Hopefully that works better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using a different approach. I created a method within the Invitation model that sends the record's information and URL to the mailer. I then added a after_create callback to that method so that the email is sent after the record is created. See below for the changes to the model.

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_save { |user| user.email = user.email.downcase }
   before_create :create_invite_token
   before_create :build_url
   after_create :send_invitation


def self.import(file, id)

  file_path = file.path.to_s
  file_csv = SmarterCSV.process(file_path)

  file_csv.each do |x|
    x[:event_id] = id
    Invitation.delay.create! x
    UserMailer.delay.invitation_email(x, @@url)
  end
end

def build_url
    @url = 'http://localhost:3000/confirmation/' + self.invite_token
end

def send_invitation
   if self.accepted == false
      UserMailer.delay.invitation_email(self, @url)
   end
end

private

  def create_invite_token
    self.invite_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end
end
```